# Having an issue with integer size limitations for my binary to decimal converter, not sure how to implement long properly

Tags: java, integer, long-integer

I wrote an app that converts from decimal to binary, octal, hex and vice versa. I initially wrote it using integers (int) however and while it worked perfectly, it stopped working after the number was a certain size. So I looked around and saw in order to get passed this I'd have to use long. I got my decimal to binary to work well but my method for converting binary back to decimal is still not working passed a certain length. Any help would be much appreciated

```
public static long getDecimal(long input) {

// Converts the input integer to a String, so we can use charAt and multiply the 1's and 0's by their corresponding power
String inputString = Long.toString(input);

// Decimal is our final decimal output, i our itterator, mult our power and num is a temporary place holder
long decimal = 0;
int i = (inputString.length() - 1);
long mult = 1;
long num = 0;

// As long as our itterator isn't below 0
while (i >= 0) {

    // Num, the placeholder, is the value of the character at the index of our itterator, multuplied by our power
    num = (Character.getNumericValue(inputString.charAt(i)) * mult);

    // Add this our final number
    decimal = decimal + num;

    // Multiply our power by 2 to get the next one
    mult = mult * 2;

    // Decrease our itterator by 1
    i--;

}


return decimal;

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest changing the `getDecimal(long input)` method to take a `String` instead of a `long`, for two reasons:

- The method expects the parameter to *look like* a binary value, such as `10010011`. That is very unexpected for a method taking a `long`.
- The largest value this method can handle is `1111111111111111111L`

It would be much better this way:

```
getDecimal(String binaryNum)
```

Notice that the parameter name hints to the read what kind of value it expects.

With this change, the method will be able to handle much larger inputs, up to `11111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111`, also known as `Long.MAX_VALUE`.

Other than this, the method seems to be working correctly.